# How to strip out values from a javascript string

Tags: javascript, dynamodb-queries

I have queried dynamo db and it is returning a string like this.

```
    { Item: 
       { password: 
          { S: 
          '$2a$10$..G.xCxVinjZQUGHxJF9a.6dSuChgOfPB0M1WjF4mrY5z7g4Gojae' 
       },
       role: { 
           S: 'hr' 
       } 
     } 
   }
```

From this string, I want to strip out password and role in different variables how can I do that?

And the dynamo DB query is like this.

```
var opts = {
  'ConsistentRead': true,
  'AttributesToGet': ['role', 'password'],
  TableName : 'users',
  Key : {
    "userid" : {
      "S" : usrname
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Is that being returned as a string or object?

Comment: If you get **`stringyfied JSON`** value from database the need to parse the JSON using **`JSON.parse`** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use . to connect the different layers.

the value Object has one child: Item.
The Item Object has two children password and role.
The password Object has one child S. Probaly to denote that it's value is a string type.
The S Object has one value, a string

So to get the password you need to work your path down the tree.

```
value.Item.password.S
```

```js
var value =  { Item: 
       { password: 
          { S: 
          '$2a$10$..G.xCxVinjZQUGHxJF9a.6dSuChgOfPB0M1WjF4mrY5z7g4Gojae' 
       },
       role: { 
           S: 'hr' 
       } 
     } 
   }
   
var password = value.Item.password.S;
var role = value.Item.role.S;
console.log(password, role);
```

Comment: OP says `it is returning a string` and not object

Comment: Yea, but what OP posted is not valid json what would be returned. So I assumed he already made it into an object himself or his framework did it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: If you get **`stringyfied JSON`** value from database the need to parse the **`JSON`** using **`JSON.parse`** method.